# Is there one word or phrase to say "outside of three standard deviations"?

Tags: statistics, terminology, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Is there a word/phrase that encapsulates:

> outside of three standard deviations

I used to think that this was called "outside the normal" but I don't think that is correct.

Comment: I think it depends on the context; one short term that I've heard is "<however many> sigma event". But that's not an adjective really, so it's not usable in exactly the same syntactic context.

Comment: Unlikely${}{}{}$

Comment: Well, people speak of "$3$ -sigma events".  Or "$n$ -sigma events".

Comment: @lulu So.. if some data were to be outside of 3 sigmas, then that is considered a 3-sigma event?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: The closest to a single word that I can think of is "outlying".  But some people might construe that to mean more than _two_ S.D.s from the mean, or some other number besides $2$ or $3$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

I would say
(adding characters)
"unlikely".